# How to substitute a function call from object that is intantiated in function under test

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit, nsubstitute

I am trying to write some unit tests. The application has a number of external API calls that I would like to mock using NSubstitute. The issue is these calls use service objects that need to be instantiated in the function and can't be passed in the constructor after substitution.

For example, in the code below I am adding an account to Quickbooks:

```cs
public async Task AddQuickbooksAsync(int accountId)
{
    var qbChannel = await GetQuickbooksChannel();
    var account = await GetAsync(accountId);
    var quickbooksBO = new QuickbooksBO(qbChannel);
    quickbooksBO.AddAccount(account);
    quickbooksBO.UpdateRefreshedTokens(qbChannel);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I want to mock the following function call using NSubstitute, but couldn't figure out how:

```cs
var quickbooksBO = new QuickbooksBO(qbChannel);
quickbooksBO.AddAccount(account);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mock a local variable. You can create a virtual method which will return `QuickbooksBO` and substitute it.

```
public async Task AddQuickbooksAsync(int accountId)
{
    var qbChannel = await GetQuickbooksChannel();
    var account = await GetAsync(accountId);
    var quickbooksBO = GetQbBO(qbChannel);
    quickbooksBO.AddAccount(account);
    quickbooksBO.UpdateRefreshedTokens(qbChannel);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public virtual QuickbooksBO GetQbBO(Channel qbChannel)
{
    return new QuickBooks(qbChannel);
}
```

After that you can substitute it in your service:

```
var s = Substitute.ForPartsOf<Service>();
s.GetQbBO(default).ReturnsForAnyArgs(substituteForQbBO);
```

You will need to figure out what parts of QuickBooksBO you want to mock. Usually such dependencies should be interfaces, without interfaces unit-testing is quite limited.

If `QuickbooksBO` methods are virtual you can do something like this to get your `substituteForQbBO`:

```
var substituteForQbBO = Substitute.ForPartsOf<QuickbooksBO>();
substituteForQbBO.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.AddAccount(default)).DoNotCallBase();
substituteForQbBO.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.UpdateRefreshedTokens(default)).DoNotCallBase();
```

Comment: That's a great solution actually which will work for me. Yes all the methods in QuickbooksBO are virtual. Similarly I am using few more Nuget packages for example Shopifysharp, Ebaysharp, Etsysharp for handling API communications. This solution could work for few cases but there are so many services that I would need to mock. I will have to write so many wrapper functions in so many classes. So is there anything else that you could recommend ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BilalYasin you can try to follow SOLID principles. In short, it's better to isolate independent functionality in separate classes with fewer dependencies. This way you'll be able to mock only the staff which is necessary. But in the end, you're right, you will have to mock a lot of external stuff in a large system. Keep in mind the goals of why you create unit tests. At first, they help you to figure out a better design. Second, they're assuring your business logic works correctly, they shouldn't test the integration with external libraries or something else.